# User defined keyword in php

Tags: php

I need to use user defined key words. That is, instead of `echo` I want to use `dislayInfo`.

Is it possible to re-difine existing keywords?

Comment: I doubt it's possible via PHP, you can probably do it if you change the C source and recompile. But why do you want to do this?

Comment: Can;t you just create a function called `displayInfo()` and make it call `echo`?

Comment: Why did you tag this [javascript][c++]?

Comment: You could always define a function displayInfo($s) in the global namespace that just echos $s

Comment: actually I am developing an non english programming framework.. it is easy for me to redefine all built in functions , but when i consider key words.. I wonder what to do..

Comment: thank you @watcher but what can i do incase to re-define the key word 'if' ?

Comment: You do what every other non-English speaking user does. You 'learn' English for the keywords.

Comment: Or create a whole new programming language in whatever natural language you want.

Comment: hi @MetalFrog , do you know the status of English language before Imperialism? I mean before 300 years? do you know the status of Tamil?

Comment: @user1143788 I have seen a lot of code that has comments and variables in foreign languages, but all function calls and definitions are in English. This is an inane request to translate all of the built-in methods and classes.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think so, but you can always use a function:

```
function displayInfo($info) {
    echo $info;
}
```

Then call

```
displayInfo("foo");
```

instead of

```
echo "foo";
```

Answer (score 1):

PHP does not support function overloading, nor is it possible to undefine or redefine previously-declared functions. 
This is from PHP manual: http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php

Answer (score 0):

There is a work around to this but it is bit tricky. You can use `ob_start()` to keep all the `output` in `output buffer`. Now, just before the end of your script, flush the output buffer in a variable and in that variable, replace your output keyword with standard keyword. Specifically, the code may go like this:

```
<?php
ob_start();//post this, everything that you will ECHO will go to buffer and NOT to output
displayInfo "My new string";
displayInfo "My multiline display
seems to work fine!";
$temp = $ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
$temp = str_replace("displayInfo","echo",$temp);
echo $temp;
?>
```

I didn't test it but I assume the logic is correct.